# Perfect squares of the form $ab^n+c$ and a Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, algebraic-number-theory

The motivation for this question comes from the following problem from an international Team selection test of 2007 from Chile:

> **Problem:** Let $p$ be a prime number. Find all pairs of positive integers $m,n$ that satisfy the following equation
>   $$(p-1)(p^n-1)=4m(m+1)$$

I have tried a lot to solve this problem and proposed it in other webpages and I have never seen a solution. Hence, I think maybe the jury who made the exam put an intractable/open problem without realize it.

Notice that the equation in the problem has a solution iff the discriminant (as a quadratic equation in $m$) is a perfect square. This led to study the equation $$(p-1)p^n-(p-2)=x^2.\tag{$*$}$$

So my first question is

**Question 1:** Given $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$. Is there any systematic study of the Diophantine equation
$$ab^n+c=x^2$$
maybe for some particular choice of $a,b,c$?.

By looking mod $p$ equation ($*$) and using quadratic reciprocity one can show that $p$ should be $\pm 1 \text{ mod } 8$ but I am not sure how much one can say.

So let's take a particular example of a difficult prime for this equation, say $p=23$:

**Question 2:** Does the equation $$22\cdot 23^n-21=x^2$$ has an integral solution for $n>1$?

If someone solve the original problem would great, but an heuristic that it may be open (based in an answer of question 1 for example) would leave me satisfied.

As this may be approached by comparing two ideal factorizations in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt{-c})}$ I will put the tag for algebraic number theory.

Comment: Have you found any solutions to the original problem?  A quick search found $(p,n,m)=(7,2,8)$ and I didn't look a lot further.  Are there other solutions?

Comment: note if a,b,c are coprime, then x has none of their factors.

Comment: In question $2$ , no $n\le 5\cdot 10^4$ does the job. So I do not think there is a solution.

Comment: For $p\le 10^6$ and $n\le 100$ , lulu's solution is the only one.

Comment: For $p=7$ there is no other solution up to $n=4\cdot10^5$

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348086/perfect-squares-of-the-form-abnc-and-a-diophantine-equation